# EditText not showing above ListFragment when fragment is displayed?

Tags: java, android

I'm building a Master/Detail application that uses `Fragments` to show the UI. I have `ListFragment` that displays a `List` and I want an `EditText` above it to enter in a data keyword that will pull from a web API. My problem is that the `EditText` is not showing above my `List` in my `ListFragment`. Here is some of my code:

**Display_Fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MyListFragment.java**

```
package com.brianstacks.fragmentandfilefundamentals.fragments;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.brianstacks.fragmentandfilefundamentals.R;

/**
 * Created by Brian Stacks
 * on 11/24/14
 * for FullSail.edu.
 */
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

    public static final String TAG = "MyListFragment.TAG";

    public static MyListFragment newInstance() {
        MyListFragment frag = new MyListFragment();
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(_savedInstanceState);
        String[] teams = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.teamList);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, teams);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public void onListItemClick(ListView _l, View _v, int _position, long _id) {
        String team = (String)_l.getItemAtPosition(_position);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(R.string.team)
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.selected, team))
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                .show();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
/*
* Brian Stacks
* Java 2
* 11-24-2014
* */
package com.brianstacks.fragmentandfilefundamentals;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


import com.brianstacks.fragmentandfilefundamentals.fragments.DetailFragment;
import com.brianstacks.fragmentandfilefundamentals.fragments.MyListFragment;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentManager mgr = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction trans = mgr.beginTransaction();

        MyListFragment frag = MyListFragment.newInstance();
        trans.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag, MyListFragment.TAG);
        DetailFragment dFrag = DetailFragment.newInstance();
        trans.replace(R.id.fragment_container2,dFrag,DetailFragment.TAG);
        trans.commit();


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // Async task method to do network action in
    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String ,String ,String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

        }
    }

    // method to get the data from ASYNC task
    private void requestData(String uri) {
        MyTask task = new MyTask();
        task.execute(uri);
    }

    // method to check internet connectivity
    protected boolean isOnline(){
        ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();

    }

}
```

It's showing my `List` but not my `EditText`

Comment: Change android:orientation="horizontal" to android:orientation="vertical" in your first *LinearLayout* (Display_Fragment.xml)

Comment: Changed that and it still did not show, the reason I set it to horizontal over vertical is that I want this to display in landscape so I thought vertical was the right choice. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where have u called Display fragment.xml???

Comment: In my `MainActivity.java` class in this line of code in my `onCreate` `FragmentManager mgr = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction trans = mgr.beginTransaction();

        MyListFragment frag = MyListFragment.newInstance();
        trans.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag, MyListFragment.TAG);
        DetailFragment dFrag = DetailFragment.newInstance();
        trans.replace(R.id.fragment_container2,dFrag,DetailFragment.TAG);
        trans.commit();
`

Comment: You got me to thinking about what you said "Where have u called Display fragment.xml???" So i went into my code in my ListFragment code and forgot to implement my `onCreateView`. fixed my problem by adding that code to my `ListFragment`. Thanks i have been stuck on this since last night.

Answer (score 0):

I had this in my `ListFragment`

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

    public static final String TAG = "MyListFragment.TAG";

    public static MyListFragment newInstance() {
        MyListFragment frag = new MyListFragment();
        return frag;
    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(_savedInstanceState);
        String[] teams = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.teamList);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, teams);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public void onListItemClick(ListView _l, View _v, int _position, long _id) {
        String team = (String)_l.getItemAtPosition(_position);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(R.string.team)
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.selected, team))
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                .show();
    }
}
```

So I changed that and added the `onCreateView` t this:

```
package com.brianstacks.fragmentandfilefundamentals.fragments;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.brianstacks.fragmentandfilefundamentals.R;

/**
 * Created by Brian Stacks
 * on 11/24/14
 * for FullSail.edu.
 */
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

    public static final String TAG = "MyListFragment.TAG";

    public static MyListFragment newInstance() {
        MyListFragment frag = new MyListFragment();
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater _inflater, ViewGroup _container,
                             Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
        // Create and return view for this fragment.
        View view = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.display_fragment, _container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(_savedInstanceState);
        String[] teams = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.teamList);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, teams);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public void onListItemClick(ListView _l, View _v, int _position, long _id) {
        String team = (String)_l.getItemAtPosition(_position);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(R.string.team)
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.selected, team))
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Fixed everything!